# Toggling a graphic using AJAX, MVC and jQuery?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have an ASP.NET MVC application with a topic page that shows a list of posts. A user can 'subscribe' to any topic, and I want this to be achieved via clicking on an image, to toggle their subscription on/off. The change in their subscription status needs to be reflected via the change in this image (illuminated image when they're subscribed, greyed out image when they're not).

The image will be rendered via CSS (I'm using a sprites.png file for this and will just specify '`subscribe-on`' or '`subscribe-off`' as the class name for the anchor/image tag).

My experience with AJAX under MVC is extremely limited, so am hoping that someone can recommend how to best achieve this? I understand the general concept of how it might work (I could use jQuery to bind an ajax call to the click event of the image, which performs the server-side operation, then I essentially want to change the class assigned to that image (to 'subscribe-on' if the user is now subscribed etc.) but I'm not familiar with the underlying code to achieve it.

I would also ideally like to toggle the `title` text of the anchor tag that wraps the image, so it prompts the user to either 'click to subscribe' or 'click to unsubscribe'.

Comment: I think you should take a look at the ASP.NET MVC NerdDinner project http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/04/28/free-asp-net-mvc-nerddinner-tutorial-now-in-html.aspx this goes through some basics of AJAX with both jQuery and MicrosoftAjax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you said, the steps you need are:

1. Bind to click event on image http://api.jquery.com/click/
2. Make ajax request to update data on server http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/
3. Handle ajax request on server.
4. Change class of image in callback function http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/
5. Change title of image in callback function http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Example:

```
$('#subscribeimg').click(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    var id = // get id for topic
    $.post('controller/action', { id: id }, function() {            
         that.toggleClass('subscribe-off subscribe-on');
         that.attr('title', that.hasClass('subscribe-on') ? 'click to unsubscribe' : 'click to subscribe');
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle Example without Ajax](http://jsfiddle.net/CqGjd/1/)

MVC:

```
public ActionResult Subscribe(int id) 
{
    // Update database to subscribe/unsubscribe        
}
```

Comment: Thanks Richard, this is almost working for me using the above. I'm hitting the Subscribe method and perform the Database tasks as required - would you be able to confirm what I should be passing back from the Subscribe ActionResult method? I currently have it set to simply return a bool (whether they are now subscribed or not), and whilst it is toggling the graphic correctly, the title attribute is not changing at all - should I be passing a different response back from a Subscribe ActionResult method (rather than a true/false back from a straightforward bool function)?

Comment: If the class is changing the title should also change. I have added a jsfiddle example that does this without the ajax request. You shouldn't need to return anything from your action as the jQuery code just checked the class to see if it is subscribed or not.